# unable to call mapActions method on Quasar component

Tags: vue.js, vuex, quasar-framework, quasar

Quasar map actions unable to update the state of the objects.

issue when i am using `@click="updateCase"` handler unable to call `mapActions` method `updateCase`.

Getting Error :

`[Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "function () { return this._data.$$state }": "Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers."`

- store/cases/actions.js

```
export function updateCase ({ commit }, payload) {
  console.log('checking i am here or not.')
}
```

- store/cases/index.js

```
import state from './state'
import * as getters from './getters'
import * as mutations from './mutations'
import * as actions from './actions'

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
}
```

- store/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import cases from './cases/index'

Vue.use(Vuex)

/*
 * If not building with SSR mode, you can
 * directly export the Store instantiation;
 *
 * The function below can be async too; either use
 * async/await or return a Promise which resolves
 * with the Store instance.
 */

export default function (/* { ssrContext } */) {
  const Store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
      cases
    },

    // enable strict mode (adds overhead!)
    // for dev mode and --debug builds only
    strict: process.env.DEBUGGING
  })

  return Store
}
```

- components/Cases/Case.vue

```
<template>
  <q-item
    @click="updateCase"
    :class="!c.completed ? 'bg-orange-1' : 'bg-green-1'"
    v-ripple>
    <q-item-section side>
        <q-checkbox v-model="c.completed" />
    </q-item-section>
    <q-item-section>
        <q-item-label :class="{ 'text-strikthrough' : c.completed }">
            {{ c.title }}
        </q-item-label>
        <small class="text-red"> {{ c.currentDate }}</small>
    </q-item-section>
        <q-item-section side top>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column justify-center">
                <q-icon name="event" size="18px" class="q-mr-xs"></q-icon>
            </div>
            <div class="column text-green justify-end">
                {{ c.nextDate }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </q-item-section>
  </q-item>
</template>
<script>
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'case-component',
  props: ['c', 'id'],
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('cases', ['updateCase'])
  }
}
</script>
<style lang="scss">

</style>
```

please take a look screenshot. [image]

if anyone solved this issue. please help me with this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Problem is probably not in click handler or `updateCase` but in the fact, that you are using `v-model` on data stored in Vuex

Comment: @MichalLevý- i got your point, but when i change v-model="c.completed" into :value="c.completed" checkbox click event not working.

Comment: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html